# Mapserver doesn't accept certain svg files as symbols

Tags: svg, mapserver

I'm  trying to add a `SYMBOL` with a certain SVG file to my mapserver configs:

```
SYMBOL
  NAME "info"
  TYPE svg
  IMAGE "etc/ico-inform.svg"
END
```

And I get 500 error when I try to open tilecache:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Nothing is logged to error log, even though I've set:

```
DEBUG 5
CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/var/www/map/ms_error.log"
```

Here is SVG code:

```
<svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>ico-inform@0.5x</title><g transform="translate(1 -3)" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><text font-family="Proxima Nova" font-size="21" font-weight="260" fill="#FFFFCA"><tspan x="8" y="19">i</tspan></text><circle stroke="#FFFFCA" cx="10" cy="14" r="10"/></g></svg>
```

If I replace SVG file with another one, everything gets fine. It seems like SVG files without `<path>` tag are not accepted by the mapserver, or something like that.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Start by just requesting your map via mapserver cgi. If that fails to give you more information then try from the commandline: /path/to/mapserv QUERY_STRING='<url_params>' where <url_params> is everything after the '?'.